# Mapping unique points to unique integer index

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, coordinates

I am not familiar with coordinate systems or much of the math dealing with these things at all.  What I am trying to do is take a Point (x,y), and find its position in a 1 dimensional array such that it follows this:

```
(0,2)->0 (1,2)->1 (2,2)->2
(0,1)->4 (1,1)->5 (2,1)->6
(0,0)->8 (1,0)->9 (2,0)->10
```

where the arrows are showing what value the coordinates should map to.  Notice that an index is skipped after each row.  I'm think it'll end up being a fairly trivial solution, but I can't find any questions similar to this and I haven't had any luck coming up with ideas myself.  I do know the width and height of the 2 dimensional array.  Thank you for any help!

---

My question is perhaps ambiguous or using the wrong terminology, my apologies.

I know that the coordinate (0,0) will be the bottom left position. I also know that the top left coordinate should be placed at index 0. Each new row skips an index by 1.  The size of the coordinate system varies, but I know the number of rows and number of columns.

Comment: Mapping usually requires a map. You can use `Map<Integer, Point>`.

Comment: @Dukeling: Could be. I haven't really understood the question...

Comment: Don't think a map is necessary, he needs to know how the mapping happens mathematically (get a function), the map is more for storage (if necessary) he just wants the index. To OP: What happened to the index 7 and 3?

Comment: Appears that you might want a generic function that maps the following: `(0,n-1)->0, (1,n-1)->1, ..., (n-1,n-1)->n-1, (0, n-2)->n+1, (1, n-2)->n+2, ...`. Is this correct? (n = 3 in your example)

Comment: @arynaq This is mapping coordinate points representing char values, so I have those indexes holding newline characters for a toString() method

Comment: how big will be the width and height?

Comment: @spj323 How about trying some of the Math libraries out there which support the Matrix data structure, for example Apache Common Maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, flip the values upside down, keep points in tact:

```
(0,2)->8 (1,2)->9 (2,2)->10
(0,1)->4 (1,1)->5 (2,1)->6
(0,0)->0 (1,0)->1 (2,0)->2
```

You'll notice that `y` affects the output by a factor of 4 and `x` by a factor of 1.

Thus we get a very simple `4y + x`.

Now to get back to the original, you'll notice the transformation is `(x,y) <- (x,2-y)` (that is, if we transform each point above with this transformation, we get the original required mapping).

So, substituting it into the equation, we get `(2-y)*4 + x`.

Now this is specific to 3x3, but I'm sure you'll be able to generalize it by replacing 2 and 4 by variables.

Comment: Of course - thank you! I hadn't thought of flipping the problem upside down to make it a bit more intuitive at first.

Comment: I didn't see the huge gap but my answer was suggesting this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the dimension and avoid overlapping you need a space-filling-curve, for example a morton curve. Your example looks like a peano curve because it's a 3x3 matrix. These curves is difficult to calculate but have some nice things. But if you just look for self-avoiding curves you can create your own? Read here: http://www.fractalcurves.com/Root4Square.html.

Comment: Um, you're **WAY** overcomplicating things. There's a nice little pattern to the numbers.

Comment: I corrected my answer. It's about reducing the dimension and non-overlapping curves. Of course he can use any self-avoiding curve?

Comment: morton codes are the professional way to go, especially for a high number of nodes with efficient storage use. Then you dont need the map anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was beaten to the formula, here is the bruteforce using a Map.

```
public class MapPointToIndex {
private Map<Point, Integer> map;
private int index, rowcount;

public MapPointToIndex(int rows, int columns) {
    map = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();
    for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        index += rowcount;
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            Point p = new Point(j, i);
            map.put(p, index);
            index++;
        }
        rowcount = 1;
    }
}

public int getIndex(Point point){
    return map.get(point);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MapPointToIndex one = new MapPointToIndex(3, 3);
    System.out.println(one.map);

}
}
```

Out:

```
{java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]=8, java.awt.Point[x=2,y=2]=2, java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]=1, java.awt.Point[x=2,y=1]=6, java.awt.Point[x=1,y=1]=5, java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0]=10, java.awt.Point[x=0,y=2]=0, java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0]=9, java.awt.Point[x=0,y=1]=4}
```